# Compare text in Unix

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to compare two text in Unix. I tried the below. It didn't work. In need to compare the first and last lines of a file.

```
firstline=`head -1 test.txt`
echo $firstline
lastline=`tail -1 test.txt`
echo $lastline
if [ $firstline == $lastline ]
then
   echo "Found"
fi
```

Surely, am missing something. Please help.

Comment: "It didn't work" is too vague. What exactly did or didn't it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps simpler...

```
bash-3.2$ if [ "$(sed -n '1p' file)" = "$(sed -n '$p' file)" ]; then
    echo 'First and last lines are the same'
else
    echo 'First and last lines differ'
fi
```

---

**Update to answer Jan's questions.**

```
bash-3.2$ cat file
-z
-G
bash-3.2$ if [ "$(sed -n '1p' file)" = "$(sed -n '$p' file)" ]; then
>     echo 'First and last lines are the same'
> else
>     echo 'First and last lines differ'
> fi
First and last lines differ
```

I prefer `sed` for grabbing the first and last lines of a file because the same command-line works on Linux, Mac OS and Solaris. The `head` and `tail` command-lines are different between Linux and Solaris.

Comment: What if the first line is, say, `-z`?

Comment: Why do you use `sed` instead of `head` and `tail` as in the question? It seems to me it's less readable and I don't see any advantage.

Comment: @JanHudec: Good questions. I hope my update covers them for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using "some sort" of bourne shell, you should (a) quote the variables and (b) need to use a single `=`:

```
if [ "$firstline" = "$lastline" ]
then
   echo "Found"
fi
```

**Update** In response to some comments, this will also work if `$firstline` is `-z`. Even in this case the if statement is *not* interpreted as `if [ -z ... ]`, at least in the `ksh` (Korn Shell) or in Bash (I don't have a system with a plain bourne shell `sh` available).

Comment: What if the first line is, say, `-z`? (I was not the one downvoting, though).

Comment: @Jan Hudec: Thanks for trying to clarify, however that doesn't hurt (at least it is not interpreted as `[ -z ... ]`).

Comment: The standard answer for the @JanHudec's concern is to write the comparision as follows: `if [ X"$firstline" = X"$lastline" ] ...`.  Ugly, but it works.  (Whoops.  Just noticed the response saying the same thing, but I can't delete the comment as far as I can tell.)

Answer (score 0):

Should be `if [ "$firstline" = "$lastline" ]`

If you omit double quotes it will not work if the line(s) contain white characters.

Comment: No, `-eq` is for comparing integers, and you'll get something like "...: integer expression expected" as an error if you try.

Comment: What if the first line is, say, `-z`?

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you have to quote the variable expansions. Plus you should add prefix to avoid problems if the strings start with `-`. And the correct operator is `=`. So it should be

```
if [ "x$firstline" = "x$lastline" ]
```

Comment: I'm really curious. I wasn't able to reproduce the "-z Issue" with ksh or bash (see the update to my answer). Does it only happen with plain old sh? (As the OP didn't tell which shell exactly).